# What is the major use of MarshalByRefObject?

Tags: c#, .net

What's the purpose for MarshalByRefObject?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Remoting; it means that between AppDomains or machines, rather than serialize and transfer the *object*, the object stays at one end and a proxy is created at the other. All method calls to the proxy are intercepted and the *call* is transmitted as RPC <sup>[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378651(v=vs.85).aspx)</sup>, causing the method to execute on the other machine (typically serialising the arguments and return value).

Note: this can lead to unexpectedly "chatty" interfaces. The object/proxy/RPC approach is now less preferable to approaches with an *explicit* service boundary; Microsoft now recommends WCF <sup>[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation), [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx)</sup> instead of remoting.

Comment: @pavel - it is fairly complex, but at least it us clear where the expensive calls are. If you mean *bandwidth*, there are ways of mitigating that.

Comment: Sometimes you do not *want* explicit boundaries, such as in scenarios listed for https://processdomain.codeplex.com/ Instead you want transparency.

Comment: in c# all reference types are marshal by ref default or how to know it, soory if it's silly question, just new with this concept @MarcGravell

Comment: @Ehsan no, they are marshal-by-val by default. Marshalling only applies when crossing app-domain boundaries, though, so it is rare that it is even relevant. To be marshal-by-ref, it must inherit MashalByRefObject

Answer (score 31):

Another important use of `MarshalByRefObject` is for implementing AOP via remoting sink-chains.

If you have an object that derives from `ContextBoundObject` (which itself derives from `MarshalByRefObject`) you can instantiate it in a separate Context within the same AppDomain and have communications between objects automatically go through the Remoting proxy system - allowing you to plug custom sinks into the Remoting sink-chain.

This ultimately allows you to 'decorate' method calls to your objects and implement cross-cutting services, such as logging and security etc.

Comment: Just thinking on these -How could we decorate such method calls to MBR objects ? Are those decorations will cost in terms of performance ?

Answer (score 10):

it basic use is for support access of objects between two appdomains and these appdomains can be on the same computer or in the different computers via remoting.

[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Any object outside the application domain of the caller application should be considered as Remote Object. A Remote Object that should be derived from `MarshalByRefObject` Class. Any object can be changed into a Remote Object by deriving it from `MarshalByRefObject`. Objects without inheriting from `MarshalByRefObject` are called **Non-remotable** Objects.