# Syntax Explanation: public class TestClass : MarshalByRefObject{}

Tags: c#, syntax

I was hoping someone can assist with a thorough explanation on the syntax below in row 3. I was trying to search for it but couldn't get something that explains it for me nicely.

I am looking to understand not just this specific syntax but the generalized theory behind it, so that if I see something similar in the future I will be able to tell what is what.

```
1 using System;
2
3 public class TestClass : MarshalByRefObject{}
```

Comment: The `:` means "inherits from". So `TestClass` inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`. Is that what you're asking? This question is better answered by an introductory book on the C# language.

Comment: See inheritance here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx.

Comment: It is just an empty class inheriting from MarshalByRefObject

Comment: check [this answer][1] for Marc Gravell


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4295901/2907017

Comment: @Code Gary, thanks that was what I was looking for. I wasn't sure what the ":" means. Now I can go read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BlackBear said and empty class inheriting "MarshalByRefObject"
this formatting might give a clearer look:

```
using System;
public class TestClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
     //No implementation
}
```

Comment: Am I correct to state then, when you use inheritance you effectively merge two classes into one, allowing you to use both the properties of TestClass and MarshalByRefObject in TestClass? 

I understand there are subtleties involved that I might not fully understand yet, but from a high level view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(VS.80).aspx

Comment: In the most simplistic sense, yes. a child class will receive all the public and protected members of the parent. from a semantic perspective its a way of defining a more specialized version of the parent class, like a School is a more specialized version of a "LearningInstitution" or a Car is a Vehicle.